# NameError instance class in python

Tags: python, nameerror

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def new(self):
        name = str(input('Name: '))
        reg = Test(nombre)
        return reg

person = new()
```

Why does this code throw "NameError: name 'new' is not defined"?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to construct a new instance of the `Test` class, and load it up with a name supplied by the user.

First, you need to correct your indentation.

Second, you do not need a `self` argument for a non-class function.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def new():
    name = str(raw_input('Name: '))
    return Test(name)

person = new()
```

Note that the more Pythonic way may be to put the logic into the constructor itself, like this.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
           name = raw_input('Name: ')
        self.name = name

person = Test()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    @staticmethod
    def new():
        name = str(input('Name: '))
        reg = Test(nombre)
        return reg

person = Test.new() #ok since new is attached to a class namespace
person = new() # raises name error since new is part of Test, not the global namespace
```

perhaps  or maybe

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def new():
    name = str(input('Name: '))
    reg = Test(nombre)
    return reg 

person = new() #ok since new is in the global namespace
```

Comment: hmmm ... any explanation for downvote?

Comment: It's not clear to me why this was downvoted, but my guess is lack of explanation?

Comment: hmmm maybe ... its got more than enough now ... theres not really a whole lot to say other than "namespace"

Comment: this lines: 1- def new(self) for this def new(): and 2-person = new() for this person = Test.new()

Comment: @cabef what do you mean?

Comment: @classmethod is totally inappropriate here

Comment: @wim you are correct... I was trying to keep it close to the original ... it is now a static method which is more marginally appropriate ...